# How do I mount my sata dvd writer in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dvd

I have a LG GH24NSD1 DVD-Writer and libdvdcss is installed. I installed Ubuntu from it so I know it works, please help.

Comment: when I type `lshw` I can't see any text containing cd or dvd

Comment: i will start by getting into the bios or boot menu, and see there if the hardware is recognized. If it is, is an ubuntu issue, if it's not recognized by bios, check the cable and ports to be properly connected and/or try another cable.

Comment: I checked the bios and it doesn't see the dvd writer but I haven't budged that wire at all since I put it there and the dvd install worked, is it possible for the cable to wear out in days? also when I put dvds in it, it does start and the tray mechanism works

Comment: Well, with hardware you never know i guess. Try checking other ports, other cables, press them well if they are loose until the bios recognize it

Comment: yeah that was it, the pin of the sata cable was loose, thanks

Comment: Great, easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you work on Ubuntu Desktop:
Check your dvd-writer with `gnome-disk-utility` , then mount it.

Comment: I don't have gnome-disk-utility, all I have is the disks application and it doesn't show my dvd writer, all I see on it are my hard disks.

Comment: To use In a terminal, you should see the dvd-writer if it is connected.

Comment: your and my english aside, the dvd-writer is connected, like I wrote, I installed ubuntu on my machine with this very same dvd